# Wordpress: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, centos, connection

Trying to fix the error due to hitting the max_connections limit i used mysqltuner to fix a few more things and apparently messed up something else very very badly.

I tried switching to 127.0.0.1:3306 but that did not work either i started getting same error but with (111) in the end.

Also whenever i got this error and i restarted mysql straight after it i got this " ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found! "
Error (2) means the file is missing but it is surely there , i did a search.

Can the file somehow get deleted?

I have looked a lot at other same questions but i did not find a fix.
I am just a newbie so not much experience in hand.

On a side note, 
I also enabled APC and started using it with W3 Total cache.

Also here is the current output from mysqltuner, the temporary tables increased alot too after i edited the my.cnf file but alas i did not take a backup!

```
    >>  MySQLTuner 1.4.0 - Major Hayden 
     >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at        http://mysqltuner.com/
     >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
    [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.6.23
    [!!] Switch to 64-bit OS - MySQL cannot currently use all of your RAM

    -------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
    [--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM 
    [--] Data in MyISAM tables: 109M (Tables: 159)
    [--] Data in InnoDB tables: 168M (Tables: 71)
    [--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 52)
    [!!] Total fragmented tables: 9

    -------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
    [OK] All database users have passwords assigned

    -------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
    [--] Up for: 8m 30s (44K q [86.443 qps], 953 conn, TX: 4B, RX: 5M)
    [--] Reads / Writes: 96% / 4%
    [--] Total buffers: 345.0M global + 1.8M per thread (100 max threads)
    [OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 526.2M (22% of installed RAM)
    [OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/44K)
    [OK] Highest usage of available connections: 34% (34/100)
    [OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/21.7M
    [OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.9% (2M cached / 3K reads)
    [OK] Query cache efficiency: 76.3% (29K cached / 39K selects)
    [OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
    [OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 1% (47 temp sorts / 3K sorts)
    [!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 39% (389 on disk / 997 total)
    [OK] Thread cache hit rate: 89% (96 created / 953 connections)
    [OK] Table cache hit rate: 97% (325 open / 332 opened)
    [OK] Open file limit used: 3% (380/10K)
    [OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (9K immediate / 9K locks)
    [OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 185.0M/169.0M
    [OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
```

---

### Edit:- Here is the output from mysqltuner just after i hit the error, the temp tables are pretty high.

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.4.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.6.23
[!!] Switch to 64-bit OS - MySQL cannot currently use all of your RAM

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM 
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 109M (Tables: 159)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 168M (Tables: 71)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 52)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 7

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1m 59s (30K q [259.672 qps], 426 conn, TX: 2B, RX: 3M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 99% / 1%
[--] Total buffers: 345.0M global + 1.8M per thread (100 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 526.2M (22% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/30K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 28% (28/100)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/22.1M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.7% (947K cached / 2K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 88.4% (25K cached / 28K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 1% (13 temp sorts / 1K sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 46% (193 on disk / 415 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 83% (69 created / 426 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 94% (114 open / 121 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (101/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (3K immediate / 3K locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 185.0M/169.0M
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
```

Comment: "could not be found" means that mysql's been told to expect it to be at location X, and it's not there. Just because **YOU** can find it doesn't mysql will search your entire drive(s) to find it. it'll look in the specified locations, and nowhere else. Ditto for the socket file.

Comment: i set up the socket location in my.cnf file
so where can it go?
also everytime i get this error mysql tends to lose connection to server before i start getting the above error. Here is the disconnection error
`database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: `I found out that my server was running out of memory. I created some swap space and it solved it for me`  
I found this answer somewhere and i feel like i have kind of same problem?
But what does swap space mean?
What should i clear? 
Very confused!

Comment: @MarcB Can it be that i messed up something bad in my.cnf files and trashed my InnoDB tables?  Read this somewhere too. Is it possible?